# Put request with Axios | React, Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, put, axios

I want to make a put request with Axios and I got this inside of my action so far:

```
export function updateSettings(item) {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log(item)
    return axios.put(`/locks`).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }
}
```

When I console.log `item` I can see all of things I've typed in my input boxes inside of that object, but later I get 404. I know that I have that URI. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 3):

a put response will need an object to send with. the correct axios for put is this:

```
export function updateSettings(item) {
    return dispatch => {
        console.log(item)
        return axios.put(`/locks`, item).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
    }
}
```

this is most likely why you get the error because the object to PUT with is undefined.

You can watch this list on the link below, to how to make the correct requests with axios. [Axios request methods](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-method-aliases)

Comment: I will give you an upvote for pointing that out, but I still get the error.

Comment: what does the error say? try to add after `then` the `.catch(error => console.log(error))` but it could also be an error on the API side, try to log as much as you can to try to pinpoint out when and where and why you get that 404 sent back to you.

Comment: do you send the 404 by yourself from your api? like `res.status(404).send('Not Found')` because otherwise your route does not exists, it might be available in a different path like `http://localhost:3001/api/locks` or similar

Comment: and you're sure you've opened the PUT version of /locks? so it know what to do when it gets a PUT request and not just GET and POST requests

Comment: I am 100% sure.

Comment: then we need you to provide more code about your API route `/locks`, because we can't be guessing. also, try the answer by @Rowland aswell..

Answer (score 3):

A **PUT** request requires an identifier(e.g id) for the resource and the payload to update with. You seem not to be identifying the resource you want to update, hence **404**.

you'd need an **id** and **item** like this.

```
export function updateSettings(id, item) {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log(item)
    return axios.put(`/locks/${id}`, item).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: add the $ to the `axios.put(\`/locks/${id}\`, item)` so it would work to just copy pasting, else the variable doesnt get added correctly

Comment: Did not know that Rowland, thanks. Know I just need to get the id to my action, because it gets undefined at the moment.

Comment: Sure thing, you can make the answer as *accepted* to help others who might have missed it as well